# What is different to use Lock() with with: and lock.acquire() in multiprocessing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I wonder what is difference of these usage of Lock() in multiprocessing. I am working with software.serial with multiprocessing and has been failing with unknown reason. Now I changed Lock: to lock.aqcquire() and it seems much less error or no script timeout happens. I am not 100% sure if this was the problem though.

Below is how I use multiprocessing. (with only one global lock). Upper def: was previous one and below one is after I modified.

I included sub-function(third) code into secondary one(called by multiprocessing). I wonder this improved by including whole function to secondary one OR different way to use Lock.

```
lock= multiprocessing.Lock()


def pjt_fade(pjt_n,flag,gap,lock): #MAX 50 MIN -2sec min 3
        with lock:
            pjt_bright(pjt_n,0)
        for i in range(1000//gap):
            with lock:
               b=i*gap
                pjt_bright(pjt_n, b) # calling bright fn of codes
            time.sleep(0.2)
        time.sleep(1) #top notch and will go fade down
        for i in range(1000//gap,-1,-1):
            with lock:
                b=i*gap
                pjt_bright(pjt_n, b) # calling bright fn of codes
           time.sleep(0.2)



def pjt_fade(pjt_n,flag,gap,lock): #MAX 50 MIN -2sec min 3
        for i in range(1000//gap):
            lock.acquire()
            brightness=i*gap
            fade_nr=bytearray.fromhex('{:02x}'.format(249)+'{:02x}'.format(16+(brightness//128)*2)+'{:02x}'.format((brightness%128)*2))
            pi.wave_clear()
            pi.wave_add_serial(pjt_n, BAUD, fade_nr)
            faderun=pi.wave_create()
            pi.wave_send_using_mode(faderun,pigpio.WAVE_MODE_ONE_SHOT_SYNC)
            pi.wave_delete(faderun)
            lock.release()
            time.sleep(0.2)
        time.sleep(1) #top notch and will go fade down
        for i in range(1000//gap,-1,-1):
            lock.acquire()
            brightness=i*gap
            fade_nr=bytearray.fromhex('{:02x}'.format(249)+'{:02x}'.format(16+(brightness//128)*2)+'{:02x}'.format((brightness%128)*2))
            pi.wave_clear()
            pi.wave_add_serial(pjt_n, BAUD, fade_nr)
            faderun=pi.wave_create()
            pi.wave_send_using_mode(faderun,pigpio.WAVE_MODE_ONE_SHOT_SYNC)
            pi.wave_delete(faderun)
            lock.release()
            time.sleep(0.2)


fading=multiprocessing.Process(target=pjt_fade, args=[PJT[0],1,int(round(np.interp(idx_s[0][0],[0,9],[20,80]))),lock]) #LOWER - SLOWER FADING
fading.start()

fading1= ..
fading2= ..

fading1.terminate()
fading2.terminate()
fading1.join()
fading2.join()
fading.terminate()
fading.join()
```

Comment: Why do you need a lock?

Comment: @Roland Smith Maybe you are right. The code try to control three different software serial ports, and specially I need to call those function quite frequently (more than 10~times per second). When I run the code without Lock, it seemed the program get confused so I've inserted Lock option to make sure each process access to its own function. But, now when I see it, it still becoming serial-coma or act strange, so maybe Lock doesn't effect anything..

Comment: @martineau so technically is with Lock: identical as lock.acquire()?

Comment: Writing `with my_lock:` is just shorthand for doing a `my_lock.acquire()` and a `my_lock.release()` around a block of statements. This works because `Lock` objects can act as "context managers". Besides being shorter, a major advantage of using it is it will release the lock even if an exception occurs within the enclosed block of statements or there's a `return` statement somewhere in the middle of them (assuming the code is inside a function).

Comment: Yes, except for the things I mentioned, it's identical. See [With Statement Context Managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) in the documentation.

Comment: @YJL Processes *cannot* just access a function in another process. Also, this seems to be about a raspberry pi? You might want to add a tag for that. And remove the multithreading tag, because that's not what you are using. Also note that the pigpio documentation says: `WARNING: bad things may happen if you delete the previous waveform before it has been synced to the new waveform. ` Since you delete waveforms immediately, that might be an issue?

Comment: @RolandSmith Thank you for pointing out and sorry for the confusion. Yes, I understand Processes can't easily share or access each other. But I am using Pigpio module to send serial wave, I was guessing even if each process work separately but where real module that sending signal is only one. So probably pigpiod module is where messed up, that was my logic. Is it reasonable? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @YJL Since they are running in different processes, the different instances of the `pigpio` objects *cannot* influence each other, *unless* they try opening the same hardware device. Normally, only *one process at a time* can access a hardware serial port (`/dev/ttyS..`). A second process that would try to open the same port would see the `open` call fail.